# Backbone.js views will not display on page load, but works with jQuery in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am trying to create a Backbone.js front end for a Rails api and I am running into a problem. I have been able to pull the data from the api and put it into a single view and a collection view. The problem is that the data is definitely there and I can run a jQuery command in the console that will append it to the page correctly however, it will not display when the page loads. It seems like maybe the javascript files are not loading in the correct order so I have tried rearranging in application.js with no luck. I have researched a lot and can't find anything that relates directly to this and I am a beginner with Backbone.js, so it's possible I may be going about this the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

#### singleUserModel.js

```
singleUser = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: null
  }
});
```

#### userCollection.js

```
userCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: singleUser,
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/users'
});
```

#### singleUserView.js

```
singleUserView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: 'li',

  template: _.template("<%= name %>"),

  render: function() {
    var userTemplate = this.template( this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(userTemplate);
    return this;
  }

});
```

#### userCollectionView.js

```
allUsersView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: 'ul',

  initialize: function( initialUsers ) {
    this.collection = new userCollection();
    this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
    this.render();

    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderUser);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render)
  },

  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
      this.renderUser(item);
    }, this);
  },

  renderUser: function( item ) {
    var user = new singleUserView({
      model: item
    });
    this.$el.append(user.render().el);
  }
});
```

#### main.js

```
var userGroupView = new allUsersView();
$('#allUsers').html(userGroupView.el);
```

Using this command in the console will display it on the page correctly.

```
$('#allUsers').html(userGroupView.el);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script probably executes sooner than `#allUsers` exists on page. When you run it inside console, the page is already loaded and therefore this element was rendered on the page.

You should put this function call inside `DOMContentLoaded`, which can be registered with jquery's constructor shorthand `$(function() { /* your code here */ })`. This will ensure that the DOM is rendered before you try to query for the `#allUsers` element. Also note, if you're loading the data asynchronously and the `#allUsers` exists only after the data is loaded, you should be calling the function after the content is rendered. but if that's the case, you'll have to figure it on your own.

Also, an useful tip: never rely on .js files being loaded in the correct order, or you'll have a bad time.

Comment: Thanks. It was correct that the #allUsers did not exist when the script was executed. I had kind of the the same problem with trying to use an external template that I had put after my source js files. It wasn't rendering the template because it didn't exist yet. I put it before the source files and it worked fine.